# Unable to use the subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

Hello I have this code :

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super.__init__()
```

But I don't achieve to use the class B :

I tried to write :

```
C = B()
```

But I get :

```
TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-ea9745abfeb2> in <module>()
----> 1 C = B()

<ipython-input-4-2d2ef2cc5406> in __init__(self)
  5 class B(A):
  6   def __init__(self):
----> 7     super.__init__()

TypeError: descriptor '__init__' of 'super' object needs an argument
```

Could you help me please ?

Comment: `super().__init__()` + proper indentation

Comment: you need to do `C=B('Bruce')`

Comment: What `name` do you expect `B` to pass when it calls `A`'s `__init__` method?

Comment: I tried `C = B("Bruce")
` but I got `TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
`

Answer (score 3):

You must provide an argument to super,

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)
```

or a default argument to `name` in `A`

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name=''):
        self.name = name

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()   # this works, but is probably not a good idea
                             # as you might need to pass a name to A, at some moment
```

maybe, in your case, `B` does not need an `__init__`?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name=''):
        self.name = name

class B(A):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

These worked for me

For python 3:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('temp name')

C = B()
```

For python 2:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__("any name")


C = B()
```